# Elasticsearch Java using very high CPU and MEMORY

Tags: java, linux, node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch suddenly stopped working due high CPU usage, and now when I restart it, it keeps using around 100% CPU and 58% Memory it doesn't drop down. There is around 1.300.000 data linked to Elasticsearch. Using Linux server Ubuntu 15.04

**default/elasticsearch**

```
ES_HEAP_SIZE=2g (half of my memeory)
MAX_OPEN_FILES=65535
MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited
```

**limits.conf**

```
elasticsearch - nofile 65535
elasticsearch - memlock unlimited
```

**elasticsearch.yml**

```
bootstrap.mlockall: true

curl http://localhost:9200/_nodes/hot_threads?pretty=true
```

> :::
>   {elasticnode}{wrdxzFcXT0aTXnp4R5KFbA}{127.0.0.1}{localhost/127.0.0.1:9300}
>     Hot threads at 2016-03-01T10:24:09.884Z, interval=500ms, busiestThreads=3, ignoreIdleThreads=true:
>          93.7% (468.4ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[elasticnode][clusterService#updateTask][T#1]'
>            10/10 snapshots sharing following 29 elements
>              sun.nio.fs.UnixNativeDispatcher.readdir(Native Method)
>              sun.nio.fs.UnixDirectoryStream$UnixDirectoryIterator.readNextEntry(UnixDirectoryStream.java
>   :168)
>              sun.nio.fs.UnixDirectoryStream$UnixDirectoryIterator.hasNext(UnixDirectoryStream.java:201)
>              org.elasticsearch.index.translog.Translog$OnCloseRunnable.handle(Translog.java:726)
>              org.elasticsearch.index.translog.Translog$OnCloseRunnable.handle(Translog.java:713)
>              org.elasticsearch.index.translog.ChannelReference.closeInternal(ChannelReference.java:67)
>              org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRefCounted.decRef(AbstractRefCounted.java:
>   64)
>              org.elasticsearch.index.translog.TranslogReader.close(TranslogReader.java:143)
>              org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:97)
>              org.elasticsearch.index.translog.Translog.close(Translog.java:425)
>              org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:97)
>              org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:84)
>              org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.closeNoLock(InternalEngine.java:990)
>              org.elasticsearch.index.engine.Engine.close(Engine.java:1147)
>              org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:97)
>              org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:84)
>              org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.close(IndexShard.java:837)
>              org.elasticsearch.index.IndexService.closeShardInjector(IndexService.java:443)
>              org.elasticsearch.index.IndexService.removeShard(IndexService.java:416)
>              org.elasticsearch.indices.cluster.IndicesClusterStateService.failAndRemoveShard(IndicesClus
>   terStateService.java:743)
>              org.elasticsearch.indices.cluster.IndicesClusterStateService.applyMappings(IndicesClusterSt
>   ateService.java:364)
>              org.elasticsearch.indices.cluster.IndicesClusterStateService.clusterChanged(IndicesClusterS
>   tateService.java:164)
>              org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService.runTasksForExecutor(InternalCluste
>   rService.java:600)
>              org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run(InternalClusterServ
>   ice.java:762)
>              org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPriorit
>   izedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:231)
>              org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPriorit
>   izedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:194)
>              java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>              java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>              java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> 0.1% (263.4micros out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[elasticnode][transport_clie
>   nt_timer][T#1]{Hashed wheel timer #1}'
>        10/10 snapshots sharing following 5 elements
>          java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
>
> org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.waitForNextTick(HashedWheelTimer.java:445)      org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:364)     org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Query example. This is the code in `elasticsearch.php`:

```
public function advancedquery($type, $query) {
    return $this->call($type . '/_search', 'POST', $query);
}
```

Any idea what is this about? I can provide any additional information as necessary.

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using to make the request? Although it sounds like it's redlining at 100% regardless of a request being made, is that correct?

Comment: Also, just to be clear, you are using AWS ElasticSearch?

Comment: @iskore `public function advancedquery($type, $query)
    {
        return $this -> call($type . '/_search', 'POST', $query);
    }`

This is the code in elasticsearch.php.

Yes without making any requests usage is always very high

PS. No we aren't using AWS ES.

Comment: Hmm. Are you trying to run PHP in a Java environment or something? Not sure how this is being connected. Also, can you temporarily block the instance from making any requests to ElasticSearch? This will show if the instance is causing the spike. If the instance is *not* causing the spike, you might need to scale up your ElasticSearch cluster

Comment: Did they work out or nah? Not exactly an answer, just a suggestion. I would write a more detailed answer but it's difficult to pin point the exact problem

Comment: @iSkore Thanks for your answers. We have been running ES without a problem with this method actually. How to stop the instance (what instance)? Sorry but I'm kind of newbie to ES. Thanks

Comment: Not a problem. So lets get your architecture down first.

You have an EC2 instance running Java - sending this request to ES?

It looks like you actually have PHP running in a Java environment or something. Is this the case?

Comment: Why is there a NodeJS tag on this?

Comment: Agreed. There is PHP code, java debug, and node.js tag. I should've seen that in my edit. I replaced `cpu` with `amazon-web-services`

Comment: @iSkore the server is on an Ubuntu VPS 15.10 and installed Elasticsearch from elastic.co using their own guide and this guide [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-on-an-ubuntu-vps)

And sending query request using that code which is included in elasticsearch.php in applications. Calling for a nodejs named users.js

Comment: I think that it all started when we ran this job. */10 * * * * /usr/bin/nodejs /var/www/html/elastic/users.js > /var/log/logfile.txt This job ran without a problem for half a day and then this usage problem occured and now whatever we do this high usage doesn't go down. Even thought there is no requests made.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the commentary. You have a `cronjob` running every 10 minutes that has *node.js* running a file in `JavaScript`. Based on your question, you have the `JS` file pinging a `PHP` file on the same server. On the same server you have a `Java` core running your `posix` stuff.

The answer to your CPU overload question is:

Choose one system. You have three environments running on the same instance. Java and PHP run on [Apache](http://www.apache.org/), Node.JS on [NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/). And you shouldn't even cross Java and PHP. That's the problem. It's like running AutoCad, Final Cut Pro, and Unreal Game Engine all at the same time... doesn't work like that.

Condense you system into one language of your choice, supported by the [AWS SDK's](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/?nc2=h_l2_d) of course.

Comment: The website is on Apach2 and Elasticsearch is on a different service on Nginx, we have always ran it seperated, if ES goes down website stays up and running. I don't think there is any malfunctioning connection in this.

We ran that cronjob for half a day without a problem, then this problem happened. And removed the job.